# How to get a user document with react firebase hooks?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, next.js

Whenever I try to make a hook for the user's document in my cloud Firestore collection, "documents", I get the error:

*TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')*

I think this is because when the page runs this code, user.uid isn't loaded yet. But, I'm not sure how to make my app wait for the user to load before creating this hook.

For this app I'm using:

- Next.js (TypeScript)
- Firebase v9
- React Firebase Hooks v4

```
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);
  // https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/v4.0.2/auth#useauthstate

  const [documents, documentsLoading, documentsError] = useDocument(
    doc(db, "documents", user.uid)
  );
  // https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/v4.0.2/firestore#usedocument
```

Comment: More code please. No one will help you because they don't know what `useAuthState()` does same as `useDocument()`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use a state management library like jotai to store the user uid after the user logs in. Chances are it's been read as undefined on the component mount and that's why the null error. Alternatively, you can have a question mark before the '.uid' but this may cause a different problem.